# PHP oop inheritance of PDO connection to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I created two classes , `USER` and `ADMIN`, and admin extends user.

I am able to get which ever data i need from the database when using object of class `USER` but i cant get any data when working with the `ADMIN` object.
the classes are as follows:

```
        class USER
        {
            private $conn;
            public function __construct()
            {
              $database = new Database();
              $db = $database->dbConnection();
              $this->conn = $db;
            }
            public function runQuery($sql)
            {
              $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
              return $stmt;
            }

        ...some functions to query the DB

        }
```

and

```
class ADMIN extends USER
{
private $conn;

public function __construct()
{
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->dbConnection();
  $this->conn = $db;
}
...some other functions to query the DB
}
```

at first i didn't include the constructor since i read that admin will inherit every not `private` property so this is my second try but in both cases i got this error:

`Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`
any idea what am i missing ? thx

**UPDATE:** i have this function for example in `ADMIN` class:

```
public function getAppeals($user_id){
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM appeals WHERE lecturer_id = :lecturer_id");
  $stmt->execute(array(':lecturer_id' => $user_id));
  $userRow = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $userRow;
}
```

the row that generates the error is this:

`$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM appeals WHERE lecturer_id = :lecturer_id");`

Comment: User extending admin sounds backwards to me - an admin is a subset of your users, not the other way around. Creating a database connection in each class is a bad call - pass an existing connection into the class from your overarching application.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yea I saw that too but thats not what he actually does if you look at the code

Comment: Are you sure you want to write your own ORM when there's many out there like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) that are feature-complete and tested?

Comment: im not sure if i want to write my own or not, but i'm sure i want to understand what causes the error before using other solutions

Comment: You need to check that your database connection is actually working.  `var_dump($db)` or better yet return the error: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: What does the Database class look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should explain your issue http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

A private property is only visible in the class in which it was defined. However, making it `protected` will allow it to be accessed from any class that extends USER so it will be visible to ADMIN assuming you run the parent constructor from the ADMIN class like this `parent::__construct();`

If you make these changes it should work

```
class USER
{
    //private $conn;
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $database = new Database();
      $db = $database->dbConnection();
      $this->conn = $db;
    }
    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
      return $stmt;
    }

...some functions to query the DB

}

class ADMIN extends USER
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getAppeals($user_id){
       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM appeals WHERE lecturer_id = :lecturer_id");
       $stmt->execute(array(':lecturer_id' => $user_id));

       $userRow = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

       return $userRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is *probably* the case here and I agree that making it `protected` is the way to go, but the error is not reflected in the OP's code because `$this->conn` is defined in both `USER` and `ADMIN`, so it is therefore accessible in both. The `ADMIN` class can access its own `$conn` property and `USER` can access its own `$conn` property, but `ADMIN` can't access `USER`'s `$conn` property. When `ADMIN` executes a method inherited from `USER` it will attempt to use `conn` from `USER`l, in which case it will not be able to access it. I'm assuming that's what's happening somewhere along the line.

Comment: @Mike I removed the `$conn` that was defined in ADMIN, therefore I think you are wrong. Both classes will I believe be using the `$conn` defined in the USER class

Comment: I wasn't commenting on your code, I was commenting on OP's code. I do agree that how you have it is correct and probably preferred.

Comment: @Mike Oh, beg yer pardon, just my confused state again